# What is the proper format of this if/else statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
function checkforinput() {

    var valid = true;
    var date = document.getElementById('date');
    var time = document.getElementById('time');
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox-1-1');
    if (date.value == "" && time.value == "" && checkbox.checked == false || date.value !== "undefined" && time.value !== "undefined" && checkbox.checked) {
        document.getElementById('errMsg10').innerHTML = "*Please Schedule in Advance or Select Now";
        valid = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('errMsg10').innerHTML = "";
    }

    return valid;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<input id="date" class="datentime" type="date" name="date" min="2015-07-18" max="2015-12-31" value="1"/>
<input id="time" class="datentime" type="time" name="time" value="1"/><br>
<h2 class="bottomOpt">OR</h2><span id="errMsg10"></span>
<h1 class="bottomOpt"><span class="adnow">Now</span><br><span id="asap">*We'll send help ASAP.</span></h1>
<input type="hidden" name="now" value="0"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1-1" class="regular-checkbox" name="now" value="1" /><label for="checkbox-1-1"></label>
<input type="hidden" name="status" value="3"/>
```

In the above code, what I am trying to do is require that the input date, time and checkbox *cannot* be empty, but they *cannot all* be selected either. It's either the user checks the checkbox *or* selects a date and time.

The first part of the if/else statement seems to be working fine, but the code after the `||` in the conditional, seems to be wrong. If date and time are selected but checkbox is unchecked, the code works. If checkbox is checked, but date and time are not selected, the code doesn't work. It still displays the `errMsg10`.

Comment: You need parenthesis...surround the parts that need to be checked together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ( (!date.value && !time.value && !checkbox.checked) 
  || (date.value  && time.value && checkbox.checked)) {
```

Because your condition is an `OR` conditional, group the 2 statements into explicit blocks so that the the correct value is evaluated.

Also it should be fine to just to check for `!time.value` instead of checking for undefined explicitly. It will take care checking for undefined, null or 0.

Also note that using `===` is faster operation than using `==`

Comment: something i just realized right now is that if time or date are selected, and checkbox is checked, then the form will go through. Any way i can tell JS that if !date.value and/or !time.value, don't let the form go through? I just tried &&|| but it didnt work. Im guessing that's not valid code.

Comment: You can't use `&&||`  as it is not valid, as `&&` , `||` are binary operators, each one of them have to be separated by 2 `operands`.

Answer (score 1):

Put in another set of parentheses to properly group the boolean logic.

```
if ( (date.value == "" && time.value == "" && checkbox.checked == false) || 
     (date.value !== "undefined" && time.value !== "undefined" && checkbox.checked) ) { 
       // bad input...
    }
else {
   // good input...
}
```

BTW, are you sure you want quotes around "undefined", to compare to that String, or do you mean the JavaScript [undefined](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_undefined.asp) constant???

Answer (score 1):

That's a bear of a conditional statement :P

After the || operator, you have double equals signs with the ! operator. Try replacing them with:

```
date.value != "undefined" && time.value != "undefined"
```